# WebAPI and OData8 conflict with Controller names in Swagger

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, webapi

I have an issue which seems common from what I've researched around my controller names conflicting and issues with swagger.

If I have two `Get()` functions in Controller one
and two `Get()` functions in Controller two I receive the error:

> Conflicting method/path combination "GET {id}" for actions

**Important to note:**

- This error only appears if within my controller I directly call the `ODataController` like below:

```
public class OrdersController : ODataController
```

- This error **does not appear** if I do

```
public class OrdersController : BaseApiController
```

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.Routing.Controllers;

namespace API.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class BaseApiController : ODataController
    {
        
    }
}
```

The main problem I have now is Swagger displaying two sets of endpoints:

one for all my `/api/<controller>` endpoints as well as `/odata/<controller>` (duplicated) and I only want the odata ones, but if I remove the Route the error will reoccur.

Comment: If you want to exclude your `/api/...` endpoints, then just add `[ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true)]` to your `BaseApiController` (and your `BaseApiController` shouldn't subclass `ODataController` - right?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> one for all my /api/ endpoints as well as /odata/ (duplicated) and I
> only want the odata ones. But if I remove the Route the error will
> reoccur

Remove both`[ApiController]`  and  `[Route("api/[controller]")]`

Here's an example of OData Controller in this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/odata/webapi-8/getting-started?tabs=net60%2Cvisual-studio-2022%2Cvisual-studio#add-an-odata-controller)

Comment: Thanks, I did remove those endpoints but apologies didn't mention this on my post but seems like removing [HttpGet] and [HttpGet({id})] fixed the conflict problem :)